# Bee command not found

Tags: go, beego

I just started learning golang and beego. Yesterday I installed golang and bee. 
I had alot off trouble getting bee command in command line to work. At a point it started to work.

Today I wanted to continue development. But again it cant find bee command. 
As far as I know its something with the PATH variable. But everything seems to be right.

Here comes the different informations you might need to help.

Go is installed and works. Go is installed in:

```
/usr/local/go
```

My project folder for go development is placed in my documents folder:

```
/Users/Anders-air/Documents/go
```

in this folder i have both bin and src. Src contains my project and packages. And inside bin you will find bee (Unix Executable File)

My bash_profile

```
export GOPATH=/Users/Anders-air/Documents/go
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Anders-air/Documents/go/bin
```

Hopes someone can help. By the way I am use OSX.

Comment: ?Do you have: Users/Anders-air/Documents/go/src/github.com/astaxie/beego

Comment: Yes. And inside that folder there is a bee folder.

Answer (score 4):

You should have a path variable named GOBIN, and its path is the bin of your go root path. Run:

`go install github.com/beego/bee`

then bee cmd can be used

Answer (score 4):

vim .bashrc insert

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.4/libexec
export GOPATH=$HOME/GoLang
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which shell you are using. You have to add the variable to the configuration file of your terminal.

In my case, I'm using zsh/zshrc.

try this:

```
go install  github.com/beego/bee/v2@latest

nano ~/.zshrc
```

Add the lines below, and save the file.

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
```

Close and re-open the terminal
Now, you should be able to run bee version

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the bee has been removed or not installed the correct way. 
After running the get command again everything works.